# JAXB Namespace Order

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to control the order of namespaces in documents generated via JAXB? I know, it is not relevant to XML standards, but somehow we need to generate namespace declarations in specific order?
For example, currently we have generated

```
<rootelement a="http://www.example.com/xom" b="http://www.example.com/crops">
..
</rootelement>
```

But I need:

```
<rootelement b="http://www.example.com/crops" a="http://www.example.com/xom">
..
</rootelement>
```

Comment: You can't control the order of attributes in elements so I doubt you can control the order of namespaces.

Comment: thanks but we can control order by using anntoation @XMLType propOrder. ALthough its not relevant for compliance with XML standards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JAXB does not directly supports that, but you can marshal your object to ContentHandler, XMLStreamWriter or XMLEventWriter and take care of the namespace and attribute ordering in there.